# How do I make grammar with optional prefix LL(2)?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar

Consider this grammar

```
start: lvalue ASSIGN expr SEMICOLON | expr SEMICOLON;
expr: OPENPAREN expr CLOSEPAREN | literal | lvalue;
lvalue: ID lvalue_tail ;
lvalue_tail: OPENBRACK expr CLOSEBRACK | ;
ID : [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
```

so `lvalue` is an `expr`, but an `expr` may not be an `lvalue`. 
with this input `var[10]`, the grammar will need 4 lookahead (ID, openbrack, literal, closebrack) before it can determine if it should choose `lvalue expr` or `expr`. 
How do I make such grammar LL(2)? 
note: `expr` here is simplified, symbol with capital letters are terminals.

Comment: Are you deliberately supporting sentences such as: myid[10]myid2[20]myid3[30]?

Comment: @user3690202 no, it's just an example, I removed many things. I will update it, putting ASSIGN symbol

Comment: I think your assumption about it requiring 4 lookahead is incorrect. expr just needs one lookahead, correct? It's either an openparen, which falls under the first category, or it is a literal, or an lval. It doesn't need (nor can it for that matter) parse the entire [ expr ], without recursing.

Comment: @user3690202 but lval is also an expr. and since lval can use up to 4 tokens, the number of K increases because it doesn't know if it should treat `var[10]` as lvalue or expr in the start rule

Comment: lval isn't an expr in the above grammar. So it knows by the second token (ASSIGN), whether it is in the first group or not

Comment: Also, it's hard to assess an incomplete grammar, which changes with each edit you make. It would be a better question if you formed and posted a proper full minimal example of the grammar, emphasis on the full and minimal.

Comment: @user3690202 sorry, I lost you.  what I meant by lvalue can be an expression is that, if you start with the rule `expr`, and you put some input var[10] (which is an lvalue), it gets accepted. And you're right after looking at ASSIGN it knows, but by then it's already 5th lookahead. ('var' - > ID, openbrack, '10' -> literal, closebrack, assign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what purpose might be served by reducing the LL lookahead of this grammar, compared with just using an LALR parser generator, since the unmodified grammar is LALR(1).

It can, however, be done by separating `expr` into `lvalue` and what we might call `rvalue` -- i.e., expressions which are not usable on the left side of an assignment operator. That might produce something like

```
start: lvalue start_tail | rvalue SEMICOLON;
start_tail: ASSIGN expr SEMICOLON | SEMICOLON;
expr: lvalue | rvalue;
rvalue: OPENPAREN expr CLOSEPAREN | literal;
lvalue: ID lvalue_tail ;
lvalue_tail: OPENBRACK expr CLOSEBRACK | ;
ID : [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
```

[This grammar is LL(1)](http://smlweb.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/vital-stats.php?grammar=Start+-%3E+LValue+StartTail+%7C+RValue+semi+.%0D%0AStartTail+-%3E+equal+Expr+semi+%7C+semi+.%0D%0AExpr+-%3E+LValue+%7C+RValue+.%0D%0ARValue+-%3E+%28+Expr+%29+%7C+literal+.%0D%0ALValue+-%3E+id+LValueTail+.%0D%0ALValueTail+-%3E+open+Expr+close+%7C+.%0D%0A) in addition to being LL(2). However, it may prove to be tricky to scale it up to include more of the language.

(In case the above link rots, it just points to an online tool which verified that the grammar is LL(1).)